# why I need to refresh the page to get the new state In react Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have this function to add a comment to the database and then render the new comments on the page In `REACT` :

```
addComment(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);

    axios
        /* the function of posting the comment first */
        .post('/api/comment/' + this.state.project._id ,{inputComment: this.state.inputComment})
        /* then the function of retriveng the data */
        .then(
            fetch('/api/p/' + this.state.project._id).then(res => res.json())
                .then((project) => {
                    console.log(project)
                    this.setState({ project })
                    this.setState({ inputComment: '' })
                })
        )
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

The problem is that I am getting the previous state before adding the last comment.

If I check the console, the function of fetching and retrieving the comments is finishing before the function of adding the comment and updating the DB, although I chained them inside `then()` after each other.

this is the function of posting the comment on `express server` which called first by `axios.post()`:

```
app.post('/api/comment/:project_id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)

    mongo.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING, (err, dbo) => {
        if (err) console.log('Database error: ' + err);

        let db = dbo.db('portfolio');
        let coll = db.collection('projects');
        let project_id = req.params.project_id;

        let comment = req.body.inputComment;
        db.collection('projects')
            .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId(project_id) }, { $push: { comments: comment }  })
            .then((data) => {
                res.json({ code: 1 });
            });
    })
});
```

and this is the function of retrieving the data from `express server` which is chained after the previous one by calling `fetch()`:

```
app.get('/api/p/:project_id', (req, res) => {
    mongo.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING, (err, dbo) => {
        if (err) console.log('Database error: ' + err);

        let db = dbo.db('portfolio');
        let coll = db.collection('projects');
        let pproject_id = req.params.project_id;

        db.collection('projects')
            .findOne({ _id: ObjectId(pproject_id) })
            .then((data) => {
                res.json(data);
            });
    })
});
```

I have other functions behave the same, I need to refresh the page to get the new state.

what I have done wrong??

Comment: Have you tried using `async/await`? It's pretty much the same as what you're doing but it'll be easier to trace how api calls. BTW, is there a reason you're using fetch at the second API call?

Comment: I am using the fetch to get the new comment added to the old ones. do you have any other idea without fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success handler for your `axios` promise is a function call, so it will be immediately called and the return value will be used as the handler. Changing the block like this should give the expected result

```
axios
  /* the function of posting the comment first */
  .post("/api/comment/" + this.state.project._id, {
    inputComment: this.state.inputComment
  })
  /* then the function of retriveng the data */
  .then(response =>
    fetch("/api/p/" + this.state.project._id)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(project => {
        console.log(project);
        this.setState({ project });
        this.setState({ inputComment: "" });
      })
  )
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```